# Update a table linked to a PowerPivot datamodel using EPPlus and it corrupts the datamodel

Tags: vb.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4, powerpivot, epplus

Using EPPlus I read an XLSX file.
I replace the data in a table and set the table range.

When I open the resulting spreadsheet I get an error:
"We found a problem with some content in 'MySpreadsheet.xlsx'.  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?" -- I click Yes and I get another error:
"Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.  Removed Part: Data store"

The error only happens after I add this table to a PowerPivot data model.

> **[EDIT]** - I created a win forms app that reproduces this problem. You
>   can download it at [here](http://www.manxsoft.com/TestingEPPlus.zip)
>
> I found the problem but don't know how
>   to fix it.
>
> 1. rename the xlsx to zip
> 2. Open the zip and browse to the xl\workbook.xml file
> 3. Look for the  node collection.
>
> Notice how EPPlus changes the `<definedNames>` collection to use absolute cell addresses.
>
> ```
> Excel: <definedName name="_xlcn.LinkedTable_MyDate" hidden="1">MyDate[]</definedName>
>
> EPPlus:  <definedName name="_xlcn.LinkedTable_MyDate" hidden="1">'MyDate'!$A$2:$A$5</definedName>
> ```
>
> If I modify this line after EPPlus is done saving then I can pull it
>   up in Excel without corrupting the Data Model.
>
> I tried changing the WorkbookXml but it is happening when the
>   ExcelPackage.Save method runs.
>
> ```
>     For Each node In pck.Workbook.WorkbookXml.GetElementsByTagName("definedNames")(0).ChildNodes
>         node.innerText = "MyDate[]"
>     Next
> ```
>
> Any ideas?

Try this first: create a spreadsheet with one table in it.  Name the worksheet and table "DateList".  Save it and run the below code on it -- it will work.

Then do this: open the same spreadsheet and add the DateList table to a pivottable data model.  Save it and run the below code on it -- it will fail.

Here's some code from my MVC Controller -- only the relevant bits:

```
Public Class ScorecardProgressReportDatesVM
    Public Property WeekRange As Date
End Class

Public Function GetScorecardProgressReport(id As Integer) As ActionResult
    Dim contentType As String = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

    Dim DateList As New List(Of ScorecardProgressReportDatesVM)
    DateList.Add(New ScorecardProgressReportDatesVM With {.WeekRange = CDate("Jan 1, 2015")})
    DateList.Add(New ScorecardProgressReportDatesVM With {.WeekRange = CDate("Jan 1, 2015")})

    Dim templateFile As New IO.FileInfo("c:\test.xlsx")
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream

    Using pck As New ExcelPackage(templateFile)
        ExtendTable(pck, "DateList", DateList)
        pck.SaveAs(ms)
        ms.Position = 0
    End Using

    Dim fsr = New FileStreamResult(ms, contentType)
    fsr.FileDownloadName = "StipProgress.xlsx"

    Return fsr

End Function

Private Sub ExtendTable(package As ExcelPackage, tableName As String, newList As Object)
    Dim ws As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet
    ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets(tableName)
    Dim OutRange = ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromCollection(newList, True)

    Dim t = ws.Tables(tableName)
    Dim te = t.TableXml.DocumentElement
    Dim newRange = String.Format("{0}:{1}", t.Address.Start.Address, OutRange.End.Address)
    te.Attributes("ref").Value = newRange
    te("autoFilter").Attributes("ref").Value = newRange
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the DateList table in the excel file look look like?  If you are going to be messing with the attributes for it make sure you update the column collection as well.

Comment: It's the same as the ScorecardProgressReportDatesVM.  One column named WeekRange.  The attributes which are being modified are to change the table to match the number of items in the list.  The columns don't change, the whole table was originally created from a list of this class using LoadFromCollection.

Comment: I added a bug report to CodePlex at https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15312#

Comment: Interesting.  Which version of epplus are you using?  I get an error in ExcelPivotCacheDefinition.cs  - "The cachesource is not a worksheet".  Seems to be the line `if (CacheSource == eSourceType.Worksheet)` where if I create a pivot table it is set to "external".  (I dont seem to have the Power Pivot addin apparently).

Comment: I'm using EPPlus v4.0.4, VS2013 Update4, .Net 4.5, and Office 365 Excel 2013 v15.0.4727.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this we had to change the EPPlus v4.04 source code.

ExcelWorkbook.cs @ line 975 was changed

```
//elem.InnerText = name.FullAddressAbsolute; This was causing issues with power pivot
```

to

```
elem.InnerText = name.FullAddress; //Changed to full address... so far everything is working
```

Comment: This may be premature.  Now I'm getting an error "The cachesource is not a worksheet"